# Where to store remote data used by directive inside ngView? (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Just for example:

I have directive inside `ngView` with this structure:

```
.directive('features', function() {
    templateUrl: '.../',
    link: function(scope) {
        // HTTP req, getting remote data.
        // Store the remote data to the scope
    }
})
```

When I change the route and return it back, the directive `link` option is executed again, the scope is empty. It need to wait some time for data-response from the remote server and then showing the data. I trying to avoid the layout stretching.

I am new to angular, I was read the documentation.

**My question is:** In this case, where the data is good to be saved? Do I need to make a controller? Or I can just cache it?

Note: This directive repeating an array (remote data) and making "features" HTML layout. This directive will be used in another routes with another behaviors.

I do **not** need code explanations, I can read docs. I accept terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the data in a service, basically to act as a cache as you mentioned. If you need to have that data available on page reloads (hard refresh, your app is reloaded again) you can store it in a cookie/local storage.

```
app.service("featuresService",function($http){
 var cachedFeatures=null;
 return{
   getFeatures:function(callback){
     if(!cachedFeatures){
       $http.get("...").success(function(data){
             cachedFeatures=data;
             callback(data);
       })
     }else{
             callback(cachedFeatures);
     }

   }
 }
})
```